# Не получается фильтровать включенные в таб разделы

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что дальше делать
В компонет prev.filter.furniture добавил новые параметры компонета
DOPSECTIONS
DOPSECTION_n  где n - это номер раздела

```html
<?
$arComponentParametersP = array(
        "DOPSECTIONS" => array(
            "PARENT" => "BASE",
            "NAME" => "Дополнительные вкладки",
            "TYPE" => "TEXT",
            "ADDITIONAL_VALUES" => "Y",
          //  "VALUES" => [],
            "REFRESH" => "Y",
            "MULTIPLE" => "Y"
        ),
);

if($arCurrentValues["IBLOCK_ID"])
{
    $arSectionParams = array();
    $arFilter = array('IBLOCK_ID' => $arCurrentValues["IBLOCK_ID"],'<=DEPTH_LEVEL' => 3,"ACTIVE" => "Y" );
    $rsSect = CIBlockSection::GetList(array(),$arFilter);
    while ($arSect = $rsSect->GetNext())
    {

        if($arSectionParams[$arSect['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']])
        {
            $arSect['NAME'] = "(".$arSectionParams[$arSect['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']].') '.$arSect['NAME'];
        }

        $arSectionParams[$arSect['ID']] = $arSect['NAME'];
    }

    $arSKU = CCatalogSku::GetInfoByProductIBlock($arCurrentValues['IBLOCK_ID']);

    $boolSKU = !empty($arSKU) && is_array($arSKU);
    $arIdsIblocv = [$arCurrentValues["IBLOCK_ID"]];
    if ($boolSKU)
    {
        $arIdsIblocv[] = $arSKU['IBLOCK_ID'];
    }

    $arComponentParametersP['PARAMETERS']["PARENT_SECTION"] =
    [
        "PARENT" => "BASE",
        "NAME" => GetMessage("K_SECTION_SHOW"),
        "TYPE" => "LIST",
        "VALUES" => $arSectionParams,
        "MULTIPLE" =>"Y",
        "SIZE" => "20",
        "REFRESH" => "Y",
        "DEFAULT" => ''
    ];
    $propertiesF = \Bitrix\Iblock\SectionPropertyTable::getList(array(
        "select" => array(
            "IBLOCK_ID",
            "PROPERTY_ID",
            "TYPE_PROPERTY" => "PROPERTY.PROPERTY_TYPE",
            "PROPERTY_NAME"=>"PROPERTY.NAME",
            "PROPERTY_CODE"=>"PROPERTY.CODE",
            "PROPERTY_IBLOCK_ID"=>"PROPERTY.IBLOCK_ID",
            "PROPERTYLINK_IBLOCK_ID"=>"PROPERTY.LINK_IBLOCK_ID",
            "PROPERTY_USER_TYPE_SETTINGS" => "PROPERTY.USER_TYPE_SETTINGS"
        ),
        "filter" => array(
            "=IBLOCK_ID" => $arIdsIblocv,
            "SECTION_ID" => 0,
            //  "=PROPERTY_ID" => $arProp['ID'],
            "=SMART_FILTER" => "Y",
           // "PROPERTY.PROPERTY_TYPE" => ['L',"E","S"]
        ),
        'order' => ['PROPERTY.IBLOCK_ID' => 'asc']
    ));

    $arPFilter = [];
    $arPFilterAll = [
        "---"
    ];
    while ($p = $propertiesF->fetch())
    {
        $type = 'catalog';
        if($p['PROPERTY_IBLOCK_ID'] == $arSKU['IBLOCK_ID'] && $boolSKU)
        {
            $type = 'sku';
        }
        $arPFilterAll[$p['PROPERTY_CODE']."|".$p['PROPERTY_IBLOCK_ID']] = $p['PROPERTY_NAME'].' - '.$type;
    }

}

if($arCurrentValues["PARENT_SECTION"] && is_array($arCurrentValues["PARENT_SECTION"]))
{

    foreach ($arCurrentValues["PARENT_SECTION"]  as $section)
    {

        $arComponentParametersP['GROUPS']["PARENT_SECTION_".$section] = [
            "NAME" => $arSectionParams[$section],
        ];
        $arComponentParametersP['PARAMETERS']["DOPSECTION_".$section] = [
            "PARENT" => "PARENT_SECTION_".$section,
            "NAME" => "Выбрать доп раздел",
            "DEFAULT" => '',
            "TYPE" => "LIST",
            "VALUES" => $arCurrentValues["DOPSECTIONS"],
        ];

        $arComponentParametersP['PARAMETERS']["NAME_SECTION_".$section] = [
            "PARENT" => "PARENT_SECTION_".$section,
            "NAME" => GetMessage("K_SECTION_NAME"),
            "DEFAULT" => ''
        ];
        $arComponentParametersP['PARAMETERS']["SORT_SECTION_".$section] = [
            "PARENT" => "PARENT_SECTION_".$section,
            "NAME" => GetMessage("K_SECTION_SORT"),
            "DEFAULT" => '100'
        ];
        foreach (range(1,5) as $k)
        {
            $arComponentParametersP['PARAMETERS']["PROP_{$k}_SECTION_".$section] = [
                "PARENT" => "PARENT_SECTION_".$section,
                "NAME" => GetMessage("K_SECTION_PROP"). " #".$k,
                "DEFAULT" => '',
                "TYPE" => "LIST",
                "VALUES" => $arPFilterAll,
            ];
        }

    }
}


$arComponentParameters = $arComponentParametersP;
?>


?>
```

```html
if ($arResult['AJAX_CURRENT_SECTION']) {
    foreach ($arResult['SECTION_TABS'] as $section) {
        if ($section['ID'] == $arResult['AJAX_CURRENT_SECTION']) {
            $first = $section;
            continue;
        }
    }
} else {
    $first = current($arResult['SECTION_TABS']);
}

?>

<?global $USER;
if ($USER->IsAdmin())
{
    var_dump($arResult['DOPESECTION_TABS']);
}
?>

<div id="prev_filter_wrp" class="w1200">
    <div class="prev_filter_wrapper">
        <? if ($arParams['TITLE_BLOCK']) : ?>
            <div class="prev-filter-title">
                <div class="prev-filter-title_img">
                    <img width="148px" height="80px" src="<?= $componentPath ?>/images/prev-filter-bg.png" class="lazy-img" data-src="<?= $componentPath ?>/images/prev-filter-bg.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="prev-filter-title_title">
                    <?= $arParams['TITLE_BLOCK'] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <? endif; ?>
        <div class="prev_filter_content">
            <div id="prev_filter_cats" class="prev_filter_cats">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#!" class="active">Для персонала</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!">Для руководителя</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="prev_filter_tabs" class="prev-tabs">
                <ul>
                    <? if ($arParams['DOPSECTIONS'] == "Y") : ?>
                        <? foreach ($arResult['DOPESECTION_TABS'] as $section) : ?>
                            <li>
                                <a class="<?= $section['ID'] == $first['ID'] ? "active" : "" ?>" data-id="<?= $section['ID'] ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $section['NAME'] ?></a>
                            </li>
                        <? endforeach; ?>
                    <? endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <? if ($first) : ?>
                <div id="prev_filter_filter">
                    <?
                    $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
                        "prev.filter",
                        array(
                            "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
                            "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
                            "SECTION_ID" => $first['ID'],
                            "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
                            "PRICE_CODE" => $arParams["PRICE_CODE"],
                            "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
                            "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
                            "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
                            "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
                            "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => 'HORIZONTAL',
                            "XML_EXPORT" => "N",
                            "SECTION_TITLE" => "NAME",
                            "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "DESCRIPTION",
                            'HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE' => $arParams["HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE"],
                            "TEMPLATE_THEME" => $arParams["TEMPLATE_THEME"],
                            'CONVERT_CURRENCY' => $arParams['CONVERT_CURRENCY'],
                            'CURRENCY_ID' => $arParams['CURRENCY_ID'],
                            "SEF_MODE" => $arParams["SEF_MODE"],
                            "SEF_RULE" => $arParams['FOLDER'] . $arParams["SEF_RULE"],
                            "SMART_FILTER_PATH" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SMART_FILTER_PATH"],
                            "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],
                            "INSTANT_RELOAD" => $arParams["INSTANT_RELOAD"],
                            "SHOW_PROP" => $first['PROPS'],
                            "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "N",
                            "BTN_TEXT" => $arParams['BTN_TEXT'],
                            "SHOW_PROP" => $first['PROPS'],
                            "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "N",
                            "BTN_TEXT" => $arParams['BTN_TEXT'],
                            "DOPSECTIONS" => "Y",
                            "DOPSECTION_IDS" => array(1016,577,990),
                        ),
                        $component,
                        array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')

                    );
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    PrevFilter.signedParameters = '<?= $this->getComponent()->getSignedParameters() ?>';
    PrevFilter.singnetSectios = '<?= $component->createSignetSection() ?>';
</script>
<? endif; ?>
```

Нужно выводить доп вкладки в компоненте из этих настроек
При переключение таба показывать только те разделы которые включены в таб

Comment: Тут вам никто не подскажет "Что дальше делать", этот форум не для таких задач